# LaTeX list line spacing with left hanging section name

Tags: cv

I have a Resume at Overleaf.com which can be accessed at  https://www.overleaf.com/read/zrnwyfhbhhps

I'm trying to have section headings to the left of the contents, which is mostly lists. So:

```
REASONS    * I'm Great Because I Am
           * Another Reason I'm Great
```

This works, but when the section heading is two line it does not. I get:

```
REASONS 
TO HIRE   * First Reason
          * Second Reason
```

[actual png of problem item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpHch.png)

Some of the probably relevant packages i'm using:

```
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{nitemize}{itemize}{1} 
\setlist[nitemize]{topsep=0pt,itemsep=-3pt,label=\textbullet}
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: The Overleaf link is broken!

Comment: Fixed Overleaf link.